# How can I block certain urls from my website

Tags: url, https

In my website, I load some files and for example one of them is index.js
If I type in google https://mywebsite.com/index.js and then it shows the code of that javascript file. 
How can I block this kind of actions and for example show a 404 page?

Thanks

Comment: What server software are you using?

Comment: I host the website on Github pages, and cloudfare.